# Firma Digital Usando c#

Tags: c#, itextsharp, firma-digital

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de firma digital con iTextSharp y C#.En mi local logro que me funcione, que me certifique las firmas (a pesar que me da un mensaje de error) pero al subir el pfx al mi Azure y el código me da este error: Signature defined. Must be closed in PdfSignatureAppearance, he trataro de buscar que puede ser pero no logro dar con el error. Alguien tiene una idea de lo que puede ser? Adjunto código y pantallazo del error de la firma:

```
certificadoDigital = Server.MapPath(certificado) + "chofer.cl_private_key.pfx";
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificadoDigital, "*****", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

llx = float.Parse(80);
lly = float.Parse(700);
urx = float.Parse(320);
ury = float.Parse(770);

using (var reader = new PdfReader(rutaDocumento))
using (var writer = new FileStream(docFirmado, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))

using (var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, writer, '\0', null, true))
{
    var signature = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    signature.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;
    signature.Reason = Session["tipodeDocumento"].ToString();

    signature.Location = "La IP del Usuario Firmante es" + Request.UserHostAddress;;

    signature.Layer2Text = "FIRMANTE: " + Session["nombreFirmante"].ToString() + " " + Session["apellidoFirmante"].ToString() +
            "\nRUT:" + Session["rutFirmante"].ToString() + "\nROL:" + Session["rolFirmante"].ToString() + "\nFECHA Y HORA DE FIRMA: " + DateTime.Now;
    signature.Layer2Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9);

    string imagenFirma = "";
    imagenFirma = Server.MapPath(imgCertificado) + "FirmaCarlos.png";

    FileStream imagen = new FileStream(imagenFirma, FileMode.Open);

    iTextSharp.text.Image signatureFieldImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagen);
    signature.SignatureGraphic = signatureFieldImage;

    signature.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r2 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
    signature.SetVisibleSignature(r2, reader.NumberOfPages, accionFirma);

    var bcCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);

    var bcKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.PrivateKey); // <---- Acá me da error

    var signatureKey = new PrivateKeySignature(bcKey.Private, "SHA-512");

    var standard = CryptoStandard.CADES;

    MakeSignature.SignDetached(signature, signatureKey, new[] { bcCert }, null, null, null, 0, standard);

    imagen.Close();
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
    writer.Close();
```

[image: Esté es el pantallazo]

Comment: Yo creo que el problema es el using del stamper. No te hace falta ni tampoco el stamper.close(). Se que me vas a decir, pero prueba primero. El iTextSharp no tiene bien definidos los IDisposable. Por experiencia, me atrevería a decirte que mejor quitaras todos los using y añadieses el using en la imagen que ahí si te hace falta.

Comment: Genial, voy a probar. Solo no entendí a que using te refieres cuando dices "añadieses el using en la imagen que ahí si te hace falta"

Comment: Me refería al del FileStream perdona:  using(FileStream imagen = new FileStream(imagenFirma, FileMode.Open))